# Web scraping paginated page using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am working on creating web scraper using html agility pack and I have a question regarding pagination.
I searched through out the web to find something to help me forward but I am no where near. I need to scrape the content of all the paginated page. Is there any mechanism to do that using htmlagility or any help is appreciated.
I also found other application like selenium and looking into it. Is there a way i could utilizse selenium along with htmlagility to scrape as well? 
Any sort of help would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You can certainly use HtmlAgility page to get all the links on a page including pagination links but your question is rather too broad to be answered. What have you tried? Here's an example using HtmlAgility pack to crawl websites: http://blog.abodit.com/2010/03/a-simple-web-crawler-in-c-using-htmlagilitypack/

Comment: Thank you Ian, I have utilised HAP to scrape website but I didn't realised the stuff with pagination. so just wanted to get fresh ideas

Comment: Pagination is often implemented as just a bunch of links (1 2 3 ... n) that sometimes evolve as you explore (... 4 5 6 ...) or do you mean something else?

Comment: I came across the second type like you said and I figured if i can scrape this one I could do any other type.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can use HAP alongside Selenium. Basically, you can navigate to a URL using one of selenium driver, and then load the HTML into HAP, something like the following :

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(driver.PageSource);
```

once you have done parsing current page, navigate the driver to the next page (locate the next page link and perform click action) and pass the HTML to HAP again. Anyway, I think most of HAP functionalities can be substituted by Selenium, so you may want to consider using Selenium only.